# Jenkins and return code from windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, ant, jenkins

I using a Jenkins (on a windows machine) job to compile some code for different targets via Ant.
For doing so, I wrap the call to the ant target within a (windows) batch loop like this:

```
@echo off
for %%t in (target1 target2 target3) do (
  ant -f build.xml build -DPARAM_TARGET=%%t
)
```

That was my first idea ... but this codes leads to an successful build even if (e.g.) target1 failed. So I put some more lines to the windows batch build step to get more overview. Also I have checekdout the code to get the same workingspace than Jenkins has to my local machine and add an test.bat to check the windows batch code can work at all.

```
@echo off
for %%t in (target1 target2 target3) do (
  ant -f build.xml build -DPARAM_TARGET=%%t
  echo ELVL: %ERRORLEVEL% 
  IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 ( 
    echo ABORT: %ERRORLEVEL%
    exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
  ) ELSE (
    echo PROCEED: %ERRORLEVEL%
  )
)
```

Testing this on my local windows machine shows the expected behaviour - here on success:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
ELVL: 0
PROCEED: 0
```

And on failure:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Work\...
C:\Work\...

Total time: 0 seconds
ELVL: 9009
ABORT: 9009
```

The same code on Jenkins do this:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Work\...
C:\Work\...

Total time: 4 seconds
ELVL: 0
PROCEED: 0
```

After using google for a while it reveals, that the return code from calling the Ant target is not properly passed to the java enviornment wherefrom Jenkins do the calls. I have tested around using "call" or "set ERRORLEVEL=1" something like this, but haven't found a soloution yet.

Anyone has an idea?
Put the loop (target1-3) into a system groovy script and hande the callc manually - does that work?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is because you read %ERROR_LEVEL% in a for loop.

I think you must use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

> EnableDelayedExpansion :  Expand variables at execution time rather than at parse time.

(ref is [here](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html))

Try to do something like this :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%t in (target1 target2 target3) do (
   ant -f build.xml build -DPARAM_TARGET=%%t
   echo ELVL: !ERRORLEVEL! 
   IF NOT !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 ( 
     echo ABORT: !ERRORLEVEL!
     exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!
   ) ELSE (
     echo PROCEED: !ERRORLEVEL!
   )
)
```

It don't explain why it runs on your computer... maybe because the EnableDelayedExpansion is already set in your dos windows.

**EDIT**

In batch-file :

- `%var%` will be expanded when the code is parsed (i.e. before execution !)
- `!var!` will be expanded when the code is executed

Since you are in a loop : `%ERROR_LEVEL%` is expanded once (i.e. just before first execution). But what you need is to re-expand `ERROR_LEVEL` for each iteration and that's the purpose of `!ERROR_LEVEL!` syntax.

Comment: Your suggested soloution works. Can you also explain the differences between %FOO% and !FOO! ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for %%t in (target1 target2 target3) do (
  ant -f build.xml build -DPARAM_TARGET=%%t
  echo ELVL: %ERRORLEVEL% 
  IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 ( 
    echo ABORT: %ERRORLEVEL%
    exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
  ) ELSE (
    echo PROCEED: %ERRORLEVEL%
  )
)
```

IIRC The issue is that ant.bat is a batch file, so you need to call it, e.g.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%t IN (target1 target2 target3) DO (
  CALL ant.bat -f build.xml build -DPARAM_TARGET=%%t
  ECHO ELVL: %ERRORLEVEL% 
  IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 ( 
    ECHO ABORT: %ERRORLEVEL%
    EXIT /b %ERRORLEVEL%
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO PROCEED: %ERRORLEVEL%
  )
)
```

*Update*

Actually there is a nicer way:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%t IN (target1 target2 target3) DO (
  CALL ant.bat -f build.xml build -DPARAM_TARGET=%%t || EXIT /b 1
)
```

Comment: As I have mentioned I already tested some stuff with "call". So your proposed soloution results in: 
BUILD FAILED
...
foo.xml:111: exec returned: 1

Total time: 5 seconds
ELVL 0 
PROCEED: 0

Comment: Updated with a nicer way

Comment: Your update results in clean and readable code. I use it now together with the SetLocale and !FOO! solution. Works perfect!