# Batch returns different result, if executed from Jenkins CI job

Tags: svn, batch-file

I am executing batch file from apache ant build.xml, running from Jenkins CI job ( Win 7 x64 Ent SP1 ).

batch file:

```
@Echo Off
svn info | findstr /C:"Relative URL:" > temp1.txt
set /p str=<temp1.txt
echo !str! @ > temp1.txt
svn info | findstr /C:"Revision:" > temp2.txt
copy *.txt temp3.txt
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (temp3.txt) do (
set s=!s!%%a
)
echo !s! >> BrandingText.PROPERTIES
```

The results are as follows:

BrandingText.PROPERTIES:

```
 @ Revision: 133708
```

temp3.txt:

```
!str! @ 
Revision: 133708
```

temp2.txt

```
Revision: 133708
```

temp1.txt

```
!str! @
```

On the other hand, if I run it locally ( call ant target, which is executing batch, from CMD from my machine ), I got correct result(s)... Why? How to fix the batch to have same and correct result both in my machine and buildserver ( Jenkins CI ) job?

I am not daily Windows Shell coder, so any help would be highly appreciated. Oh, and plus that `NewLine character` in the end of

> Revision:

is also damn nasty one... Would be great to get rid of it :)

Comment: Would this comment serve as explanation for this behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19360361/132296 ? I think I tried with %%, but then it did not work even from my machine...

Comment: Exactly, from where do you want to remove the nasty new line character?

Comment: From temp2.txt file. :)

Comment: See updated answer. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Back up... what's your end goal here?  I don't think you need to execute commands piping output to files and parsing them.   Specifically, you can get the svn rev from an environment variable.  see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin

Comment: Because in my currrent companies infrastructure we build both from CI and workstation environments, therefore, in workstation I got no access to any SVN Plugin. It is all said in the Tile of this Question ;)

Comment: yeah... you're making things hard on yourself.  Everywhere builds have to work locally and ideally the CI build is just like that (if not the build sucks).  Why do you need any svn revision information on a local build? It's not relevant - as there will be local modifications anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    rem and here starts the code
    ....
```

Maybe, this should work

If delayed expansion is off, `!str!` (with the variable defined with valid content), returns `!str!`. No delayed expansion, so no translation of `!` variables.

BUT, `echo %str% @ > temp1.txt` should work.

EDITED - for the nasty new line character

```
<temp2.txt set /p t2=
<nul       set /p t2=%t2%> temp2.txt
```

Obviously, after the temp2.txt file has been generated

Comment: Thank you. No, it do not work; I got empty temp2.txt now. Thanks again for effort and time. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a terrible idea to have your build script aware of version control - those concerns should be separate.

Having said that, you're going to have a better time if you just set the output of `svnversion` to a variable or even write it out to a file.

Comment: We do that also, but in some rare cases... it is nice to have these values distributed within build infrastructure. :) It is not intended to be dependant or even aware.. if there is any value, it is used, if it is not, build.xml do not care. Simple as that.