# Jenkins batch file ERRORLEVEL unchanged

Tags: batch-file, uwp, jenkins-plugins, psexec, windows-task-scheduler

Before I get a downvote, I have checked the existing links like: [jenkins return code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355114/jenkins-and-return-code-from-windows-batch) But could not reproduce the fix. I have majorly two issues:

**First:**
So my script is:

```
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    REM Installing the application
    "%PSTOOLLOCATION%\PsExec.exe" \\%HOSTNAME% cmd /c schtasks /run /TN %SCHEDULEDINSTALLERTASKNAME%

    REM Waiting for installation to complete
    :loop
    %PSTOOLLOCATION%\PsExec.exe \\%HOSTNAME% cmd /c schtasks /Query /tn %SCHEDULEDINSTALLERTASKNAME% /fo table /nh | find "Ready"
    echo !ERRORLEVEL!
    echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    echo ERRORLEVEL
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==1 (
      echo "Installation in progress"
      goto :loop
    ) ELSE (
      echo "Installation complete"
    )
```

The outputs are always "1" no matter if I enable/disable setlocal command.
The only change in environment I could see is the introduction of another UWP surface (HOSTNAME) which is connected through jenkins slave.

I want to have the status updated in each loop run.

**Second:**
The command which should get the complete status of task schedular gives just the first line as output:
Command:

```
cmd /c "%PSTOOLLOCATION%\PsExec.exe \\%HOSTNAME% cmd /c schtasks /query /tn %SCHEDULEDINSTALLERTASKNAME% /fo list" > status.txt
```

Expected output:

```
Folder: \
HostName:      CTSURFACE1
TaskName:      \TASKNAME
Next Run Time: N/A
Status:        Ready
Logon Mode:    Interactive/Background
```

Output received:

```
Folder: \
```

This only reproducible when the command is run via batch file (run.bat) in jenkins. If I expand this command in batch section of jenkins job, this works fine. Any open bug for this?

Comment: First, run in a command prompt window `if /?` and you can read in output help about the `if errorlevel X` syntax which means __IF__ exit code of command/application is __greater or equal X__. `if errorlevel X` or the opposite `if not errorlevel X` (lower than X) works anywhere since MS-DOS even in a command block without using delayed expansion and should be therefore always used instead of `if %ERRORLEVEL% == X` or `if !ERRORLEVEL!  == X`.

Comment: Thanks Mofi. But the concern is not if condition here. The actual problem lies with the values of ERRORLEVEL. The loop never changes the errorlevel whereas on the machine, the status has changed.

Comment: Second, the real problem. It is expected by you that `| find "Ready"` results in processing the output of `schtasks`. This is not true. `find` is executed on local machine processing output of __PsExec__. You have to escape redirection operator `|` with `^` to get it first interpreted as literal character on `cmd.exe` parsing entire __PsExec__ command line before running it, i.e. use `^| find "Ready"`.

Comment: Yes. That fixed my problem. Very minor mistake! :)
Any inputs for status.txt problem?

Comment: You also do not need to use `PSEXEC` to query another computer. `SCHTASKS` has the option to specify the computer you want to query.